# Latest non-Nothing values in a list

Tags: list, haskell, option-type

I have recently started learning Haskell and I hope you can help with a list transformation question.

I have a Maybe list of a custom data type, simplified to Strings for this forum, and I want transform it to replace Nothing values with the most recently seen value. See below:

```
Input: [Nothing, Just "Hello", Nothing, Nothing, Just "World", Nothing]
Output: [Nothing, Just "Hello", Just "Hello", Just "Hello", Just "World", Just "World"]
```

Is this possible in Haskell? Any pointers will be much appreciated.

Comment: You could try to implement this using recursion.

Comment: You may find that the simple recursive approach doesn't quite work.  One extra hint is to make a helper function to do the recursion, and pass that helper function the input list along with an additional parameter: the most recently seen value.

Comment: Thank you! I'll take a look into that.

Comment: Your output type doesn't reflect the fact that there can't be any `Nothing`s after the first `Just`. This seems rather unsatisfying. What do you want this function for?

Answer (score 9):

Here's a very concise and elegant way of implementing this:

```
import Control.Applicative

f = scanl1 (flip (<|>))
```

Doing `f [w,x,y,z]` yields `[w, x <|> w, y <|> x <|> w, z <|> y <|> x <|> w]`, and chaining `Maybe`s with `<|>` gives you the first one that's `Just`, or `Nothing` if they're all `Nothing`.